# Export to Word works locally but not on IIS6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-word

I have an aspx page that downloads creates and downloads the word document. for that i am using below code. which works fine on our local system as well as on IIS7 / IIS8. but when i host the application IIS6, it downloads corrupt document with the message "The Office Open XML file cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents."

I have tried all the possible solutions but nothing worked.

Please help me.

Below is the code.

```
        string strfilename = Server.MapPath("~/Document.doc");
        byte[] Content = File.ReadAllBytes(strfilename);
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Download.doc");
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.OutputStream.Write(Content, 0, Content.Length); 
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        //Response.End();
```

I have commented Response.End(); because it was throwing an exception of "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is Optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack".

Comment: Are you trying to send a binary Word document (.doc extension) or an OpenXML Word document (.docx extension)? The error message suggest that you created an OpenXML document (but why the .doc extension then?) and that this document simply is corrupted. What happens if you take the document from the server manually (e.g. by copying in Explorer) and try to open the file in Word?

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` instaed of `Response.End();`

Comment: That is because you have made some mistake in openXML coding may be some tags are not matching. or left unclosed. Download OpenXML sdk and open the generated document in it and look through the tags and fix the error

Comment: but if that's the case then it should also not work on my other server as well as on my local machine. its giving this error only in one server.

Comment: can you share one generated doc with me

Answer (score 0):

Try ,

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file);
```

Comment: what is the value of  AspBufferingLimit  in your IIS ? increase it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but i found the answer myself.

The code was fine but the Office dlls were not registered in GAC.

so i downloaded the PIA from below link, installed it on my server and it started to work :)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=18346[1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=18346)